# java.awt.Robot equivalent in OS X Cocoa?

Tags: java, cocoa, macos

Is there any library equivalent to the Java Robot class in OSX/Cocoa?

Thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545768/how-do-you-test-your-cocoa-guis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is No such Library

You can check following link for help

http://mac.wareseeker.com/free-robocode-tracking-for-robot-class/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29

**It will be easy for us to provide you the alternative if we  know what you are up to as there are lots of work arounds.**