# How to simulate user input in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, window-management

On windows, and with c#, I was able to capture another window's "screen", use that for processing, and then send user input events to that window. (which were generated by the program).

I would like to do the same with objective-c and within Mac OS X. So! Any resources or even a name for what I'm trying to do would be great. It's very frustrating to try and find information on this when the only ways i can think to phrase my searches are too ambiguous.

Thanks!

EDIT: As a specific example, there might be a particular game that I want to make an AI for. In that case I would need to be able to send mouse and keyboard events to the game.

Comment: Usually on Mac OS X, you have to go quite far out of your way to inspect windows/memory of other processes.

Comment: See also: ["How do you test your Cocoa GUIs?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545768/how-do-you-test-your-cocoa-guis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do automated user interface testing, look at [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/products/index.php), [eggPlant](http://www.testplant.com/), [expect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html) and [OS X Accessibility](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXIntro/OSXAXintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH205-BABGJCGG). If you're looking to programmatically control another program, use [scripting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001982-BCICHGIE) (if you wrote the program to control, add scripting support; otherwise, see what scripting support the program offers), or try [Automator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Automator.html).

Comment: Thanks! Though I am trying to write an AI for a simple game - i don't think it would have scripting support. It looks like eggPlant does what i'm *trying* to do, though for different reasons.