# How to write a unit test that checks that pressing the button will cause to calling the proper IBAction?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ibaction, ocmock

I need to write a unit test that checks that pressing the button will cause the proper `IBAction` to be called.

Here is my test method:

```
- (void)testWhether_loginBtnTapped_IsCalledAfterUserTapLoginButton
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    GoingToLoginViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GoingToLoginVC"];

    id vcMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:myViewController];

    [[vcMock expect] loginBtnTapped:[OCMArg any]];

    [myViewController.loginBtn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [vcMock verify];
}
```

When I run the test I have log message:

```
error: testWhether_loginBtnTapped_IsCalledAfterUserTapLoginButton (Ticket2Tests) failed: OCPartialMockObject[GoingToLoginViewController]: expected method was not invoked: loginBtnTapped:<OCMAnyConstraint: 0xfd3aeb0>
```

And when I run my app on the simulator the button works appropriately and `- (IBAction)loginBtnTapped:(id)sender;` was called.

What did I do wrong and what should I do to make the test pass?

Comment: Please have a look at this question: [How do you test your Cocoa GUIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545768/how-do-you-test-your-cocoa-guis). The answer is perfectly valid for Cocoa Touch. You may test the actual interaction with UI tests with, for example, [Keep It Functional (KIF)](https://github.com/square/KIF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `myViewController.loginBtn` is nil, as you haven't loaded the view. Try calling `[myViewController view]` to cause the view to be loaded first.

Comment: Thank you Christopher Pickslay). Now i have added `[myViewController view];` after `GoingToLoginViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GoingToLoginVC"];` and my test pass with success. Also i have change `[[vcMock expect] loginBtnTapped:[OCMArg any]];` to `[[vcMock expect] loginBtnTapped:myViewController.loginBtn];` for more accuracy